# Check for duplicate elements in lists in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that could have as many as N keys in it, with a list attached to each key. I need to check for unique elements in one list, out of all the other lists in the dictionary.

Example of dictionary structure:

```
dict = {'N1': ['e1', 'e2', ...], 'N2': ['e1', 'e3', ...], 'N...': [....], ....}
```

I then need to append these to a different dictionary under the same key, but with only the unique elements in a list

```
return_dict = {'N1': ['e2'], 'N2': ['e3'], 'N...': [...], ...}
```

I hope there is enough information here to understand what I'm asking. If someone could help me figure out a way to easily do this, that would be much appreciated.

Edit: I'm not allowed to import anything as well. No handy imports today. :(

Answer (score 2):

For a solution involving no imports (*sigh*), we first "invert" the dictionary by listing per value what lists it is in:

```
d = {'N1': ['e1', 'e2'], 'N2': ['e1', 'e3']}

inverse = {item: [key for key,ls in d.items() if item in ls]
           for item in set(sum(d.values(),[]))
          }
```

In our case, `inverse` is now `{'e1': ['N1', 'N2'], 'e3': ['N2'], 'e2': ['N1']}`. Now we just need to "invert" this dictionary again, making sure to ignore duplicates:

```
ret = {key: [item for item in count if key in count[item] and len(count[item]) == 1]
       for key in set(sum(count.values(),[]))
       }
```

`ret` is then `{'N1': ['e2'], 'N2': ['e3']}`.

---

The most interesting part of this is probably the hacky reimplementation of `itertools.chain.from_iterable` as `lambda x: sum(x, [])`: The not very often used second parameter of `sum` allows you to set a starting value, and since you can "add" lists together, this will take a sequence of lists and make a new big list.

Comment: This almost works for me, the only issue is the first element it sees, if it is in fact a duplicate, it won't know and will count it as unique.

Comment: @Kezaraux You mean if a list contains duplicates within itself? Fixed it in an edit by using set on `d[key]`.

Comment: When I run that I get in my return_dict: `{'N2': ['e3', 'e1'], 'N1': ['e2']}` when I was expecting: `{'N2': ['e3'], 'N1': ['e2']}`.

Comment: Oh.. I realize I misunderstood your task. I thought you wanted to deduplicate the lists, not remove all copies if a duplicate is found. I will fiy it tomorrow.

Comment: No worries. I guess I probably could have phrased my question better. Thank you for helping me though. It is much appreciated.

Comment: @Kezaraux Changed my answer so it conforms to your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, as a note, you should avoid using `dict` as a variable name, as that shadows the name of a built-in type.

Now, if I understand your question, this should do what you are looking for:

```
from collections import Counter
d = {'N1': ['e1', 'e2'], 'N2': ['e1', 'e3']}
# Copy the dictionary if you want to keep the original one. Note in particular
# that `return_dict = dict(d)` will not be sufficient as we need a deep copy
return_dict = {k: list(v) for k, v in d.items()}
# Count the occurrences of list elements
counts = Counter([a for v in return_dict.values() for a in v])
# Remove elements that appear more than once
for v in return_dict.values():
    for a in v:
        if counts[a] > 1:
            v.remove(a)
print(d)  # Prints {'N2': ['e1', 'e3'], 'N1': ['e1', 'e2']}
print(return_dict)   # Prints {'N1': ['e2'], 'N2': ['e3']}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm not allowed to use any imports. This is a wonderful solution that works for me otherwise! Just need to get around that no import restriction.

Comment: FYI, you can use [copy module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) to copy a dictionnary (shallow or deep)

Comment: @Kezaraux then implement a `Counter`. It's straightforward, this solution is practically pseudocode. We're not here to do you homework for you. You've got an answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

All right, going from L3viathan's answer, I started fiddling with a similar approach. This is going to be really sloppy and horrible, but it works for my needs. What I found to work was this:

```
ret = {}
seen = set()
repeated = set()
for key in hash_dict:
    for item in hash_dict[key]:
        if item in seen:
            repeated.add(item)
        else:
            seen.add(item)
for key in hash_dict:
    ret[key] = ret.get(key, [])
    for item in hash_dict[key]:
        if item not in repeated:
            ret[key].append(item)
return ret
```

Looks really sloppy to me, but since I don't have an extensive knowledge of python, and I'm limited by not being able to use imports, this is what I could do.

Edit: The different variable names are like that because I copied this directly from my project that I was working on.